# How to align views in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to put an `edittext` and a button with a image as a background horizontally within a `linearlayout` but my button happened to be shifted a bit above which look very odd. I want to make the `edittext` and `button` aligned from top as well as bottom.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="3">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox2"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Type to text"
    android:layout_weight="2.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/send2323"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <requestFocus />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

for both button and edittext

Answer (score 1):

It is because of you make EditText: android:layout_height="50dp", and Button: android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Also pay attention that parent align only be useful for RelativeLayout
try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="3">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox2"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Type to text"
    android:layout_weight="2.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/send2323"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```